# PHP version / honeypot server / is 5.2 vulnerable?

Tags: php

I read this article recently on Ars: http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/php-bug-allowing-site-hijacking-still-menaces-internet-22-months-on/

I have some very old PHP servers still running some legacy code.  They use PHP version `5.2.17`

The article above states that `PHP versions prior to 5.3.12 and 5.4.2 are vulnerable.`

The fact that they mention 5.3.x and 5.4.x, it makes me think that 5.2.x is NOT vulnerable - is this correct?

Thank you to anyone who can confirm and provide a reputable source for this.

Comment: PHP 5.2 IS vulnerable: http://www.cvedetails.com/version/106044/PHP-PHP-5.2.17.html

Comment: The magic word is __prior__: 5.2.x is __prior__ to 5.3.x; 5.3.11 is __prior__ to 5.3.12.... 5.2 was already end of life when this bug was patched in the two active branches at the time (5.3 and 5.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *PHP versions prior to 5.3.12 and 5.4.2 are vulnerable.*

5.2.17 is very much prior to both of those. If you look on http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.3, bug #61910 was fixed only in the 5.3 and 5.4 branch.

Having said that, the wording may be ambiguous. PHP 5.2 may be left out because it was not supported anymore. Or it may have been left out because the vulnerability only existed in 5.3+. I can't find definitive proof one way or the other.

Comment: Any way to patch without changing to a new version?

Comment: See  the bug report, Rasmus himself posted a workaround: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61910

Comment: Perfect: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(%2d|-)[^=]+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1? [L]`